# Deriving the logistic distribution from two exponential distributions. Is there no division by zero?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

How do I prove that if $X, Y \sim \operatorname{Exponential}(1)$ then
$\mu-\beta\log\left(\frac X Y \right) \sim \operatorname{Logistic}(\mu,\beta)$?

Shouldn't it always cause a division by zero?

I feel totally naïve here!

Comment: No.  $Y$ is almost surely positive.  Anyway, I think you want independence of $X,Y$.

Comment: Haven’t worked out the problem, but division by zero shouldn’t be a problem here since $Y$ is zero with zero probability.

Comment: Please use a title that asks the actual question. And edit to show your work.

Answer (score 0):

Let $Z = \frac{X}{Y}$.

Then $F_Z(z) = \Pr[Z \leq z] = \Pr[X/Y \leq z] = \int_0^\infty \Pr[X \leq yz]f_{Y}(y) dy = \int_0^\infty F_X(yz) f_{Y}(y) dy$

You can now calculate $f_Z$ from here. Does that help?

Comment: Shouldn't $F_Z(z) = \int_0^\infty F_X(yz) f_{Y}(y) dy$ be equal to $1/(1+\exp(-z))$? I don't see how that arises from inserting $F_X(yz)=1-\exp(-yz)$ and $f_{Y}(y)=\exp(-y)$.